# Running two different cameras from uvc_camera driver?

Tags: ros, gscam, camera, stream, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a whole robotic system in which I have a camera mounted on a robotic arm.
One more camera is mounted on the top of a frame from which I can see my whole robotic system.

How can I start two cameras from just one camera driver?
I have been able to start the two cameras with two different drivers.One was uvc_camera and the other one was gscam.

Please let me know
thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61198/running-two-different-cameras-from-uvc_camera-driver?/) by [Rohitdewani](https://answers.ros.org/users/4133/rohitdewani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do that by starting two different instances of uvc_camera under different node name or probably under different namespace and in parameters just change the device name.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3